# Navigation drawer and fragments running but logcat giving errors

Tags: android, android-fragments, logcat, navigation-drawer

I have currently implemented a navigation drawer with fragments using the tutorial over here: http://www.codeofaninja.com/2014/02/android-navigation-drawer-example.html

Now I have the program running and it works fine as far as I can tell. But the problem is that logcat is giving me errors despite the program running smoothly.

The following is the logcat report:

```
07-30 15:21:10.584: W/dalvikvm(12501): No implementation found for native Ldalvik/system/VMRuntime;.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501): Pause GC
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501):    at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java)
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java)
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501):    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc(Native Method)
07-30 15:21:10.589: E/ActivityThread(12501):    ... 16 more
07-30 15:21:10.724: D/dalvikvm(12501): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 310K, 13% free 10664K/12188K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
07-30 15:21:10.764: D/dalvikvm(12501): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 20K, 13% free 10768K/12288K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
07-30 15:21:10.764: I/dalvikvm-heap(12501): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.774MB for 1127536-byte allocation
07-30 15:21:10.804: D/dalvikvm(12501): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 12% free 11869K/13392K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
07-30 15:21:10.829: D/AbsListView(12501): Get MotionRecognitionManager
07-30 15:21:10.974: D/libEGL(12501): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
07-30 15:21:10.979: D/libEGL(12501): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
07-30 15:21:10.984: D/libEGL(12501): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
07-30 15:21:10.989: E/(12501): Device driver API match
07-30 15:21:10.989: E/(12501): Device driver API version: 23
07-30 15:21:10.989: E/(12501): User space API version: 23 
07-30 15:21:10.989: E/(12501): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Fri Mar 21 13:52:50 KST 2014 
07-30 15:21:11.079: D/OpenGLRenderer(12501): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Does anyone know what is wrong? Thanks for your time.

P.S. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Note 2 International Variant (Android 4.4.2)

Comment: does it appear only when your app is running?

Comment: Yes, I have a filter set up to show only app related messages.